# Authenticating Client Certificates from Different Issuer

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, virtualhost, certificate, certificate-authority

Ok, here's the scenario. A company called "Corp" issues SSL certificates to all their employees for accessing Corp's web resources. Corp also provides a certificate for their Certificate Authority so that their employees can install this as a trusted CA.

I am building a tool that is outside of Corp's network, but I would like to use the SSL certificates that all of the employees have installed to identify them when they use this tool (since only Corp employees should be able to use this tool). This is running on an Apache 2.2 install on Amazon's linux distro. Here is what I have tried so far:

1) I created and self-signed a SSL certificate for the server to use to serve up HTTPS ("privatekey.pem" and "server.crt")

2) I copied Corp's CA certificate to the server (corp-ca.crt)

3) I used the following VirtualHost configuration for Apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName toolname.thirdparty.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ServerAdmin admin@myemail.com
        ErrorLog logs/toolname-error_log
        CustomLog logs/toolname-access_log common
        <Directory "/var/www/html">
                AllowOverride all
        </Directory>
        SSLEngine On
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/server.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/privatekey.pem
        SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/corp-ca.crt
        SSLVerifyClient require
        SSLVerifyDepth 1
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</VirtualHost>
```

When I try to access one of Corp's websites, I can select my client certificate from them and it works, so I know the client certificate is installed properly. When I do this with `SSLVerifyClient optional`, the page loads fine over HTTPS so I know my server's SSL setup is good. With `SSLVerifyClient required`, though, I get an `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` saying:

"Unable to make a secure connection to the server. This may be a problem with the server, or it may be requiring a client authentication certificate that you don't have."

So this brings up the question I have to ask: is what I'm trying to do even possible? Can I use a client certificate issues by someone else to verify their identity on my own site? If that's actually possible, how would I go about doing it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Corp obviously holds a CA root cert maybe along with an intermediate cert. 
So in this scenario, you can not use a self-signed cert with Corp's CA chain. 
Your certificate has to be "signed" by Corp's Root or Intermediate cert, with [openssl ca](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/ca.html) command.

Thus you have to send a CSR to Corp's admin to give you a signed/valid cert back to use with your Apache.

Edit: 
For more information you can use [openssl s_client](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/s_client.html) command to see your SSL setup. Eg: `openssl s_client -connect myextapp.com:443`
You will see an output of certificates' chain, that you have used to configure apache.

Comment: Not true if it's your server's certificate. For the server one you can have a certificate signed from whatever CA is reconised by browsers, it does not have to be the same as the one signing the client ones. For the client ones you can verify them based on one or more CA certificates that sign the client certificates

Comment: @Fredi Asker wants to use self-signed cert with Corp's CA cert. at step 2. Apache can not make a chain of certificates which they are irrelevant.

Comment: i've done that. It's not nice but it works. The CA's that sign the server certificate and the accepted client ones don't need to have the same root or intermediate certs. The only thing that's needed is the CA that signs the client ones to in in the bundle included in one of http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslcacertificatefile or http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslcacertificatepath

Comment: Vouv. frankly i have never tried that, but sure i wil :) which browser you have tested this situation?

Comment: standard browsers, google chrome, firefox (sorry, i'm a linux guy so no IE), you just need apache to have all the certificate chain, the public keys. consider the server chain and client chain two separate things. I have a flacky connection, i'll post an answer later in case.

Comment: @Fredi if you could post an answer that would be awesome. I have done what it sounds like you're suggesting (including the CA that signs the client ones into the SSLCACertificateFile), but it was unsuccessful, so more details would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration seems correct, assuming the certificate of the CA that signs your client certificates is fuond in this file:

`/etc/ssl/corp-ca.crt`

I would suggest you to add another directove too, this one:

SSLCADNRequestFile

That shoud point to a file that is a concatenation of all the CA's that can sign your client's certs, and another caveat, see this apache bug about that list (a list of acceptable CA's sent from apache to the client):

https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=12355

That and the fact that the CA's may not be known to the browser can give you the exact message you got.

In this case, first make sure to install the client certificate to your browser, you need a pkcs12 file which includes both the private key and certificate. Once done this, all should work fine.

To check if that is the case you can use curl:

`curl -k -E YOUR_CLIENT_CERT.pem --key YOUR_CLIENT_KEY.pem https://toolname.thirdparty.com`

`-k` because you are not checking server's certificate in this case.